# Racket/Scheme - Replacing an item with another element in a non flat list

Tags: list, recursion, replace, scheme, racket

I'm trying to replace an item with another item when given a list. I've gotten to code out a procedure that can do this for a flat list but I was not sure how to implement it when the list is not a flat list.
This is the current code for the replacer:

```
(define repl
  (lambda (exp1 exp2 exp3)
    (cond
      ((null? exp3) exp3)
      ((equal? (first exp3) exp1) (cons exp2 (repl exp1 exp2 (rest exp3))))
      (else (cons (first exp3) (repl exp1 exp2 (rest exp3)))))))
```

I'm very new to coding in racket so I wasn't sure how I would then be able to apply this when it's not a flat list
A valid test case is the following

```
(repl 'a 'b '((f a) (f (a)))) => '((f b) (f (b)))
```

But when I run my current procedure it produces

```
'((f a) (f (a)))
```

How would I go about applying my current code to work for non flat lists?

Comment: `repl` is a bad name, as it stands for "read eval print loop" and can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider a new case in the recursion: what if the current element in the list is *another list*? in that case, we need to do a deeper recursion, and descend over both the current element and the rest of the list. Otherwise, check if the current element needs to be replaced, or leave it alone. This is what I mean, notice that this is a faster solution when we only want to replace atoms:

```
(define repl
  (lambda (exp1 exp2 exp3)
    (cond
      ; base case: list is empty
      ((null? exp3) exp3)
      ; base case: current element is an atom
      ((not (pair? exp3))
       ; should we replace current element?
       (if (equal? exp3 exp1) exp2 exp3))
      ; recursive case: current element is a list
      (else
       ; recursively descend over both sublists
       (cons (repl exp1 exp2 (first exp3))
             (repl exp1 exp2 (rest exp3)))))))
```

It works as expected, no matter how deeply nested is the element that you want to replace:

```
(repl 'm 'x '((a (b (c (d e (f (m))) h) i (j) (k (l (m)))) n) o (p)))
=> '((a (b (c (d e (f (x))) h) i (j) (k (l (x)))) n) o (p))
```

**EDIT**: Now, if the elements you want to replace are lists themselves, we have to shuffle around the conditions. Below you'll find the implementation, it's more general than my previous solution, but also it's slower. Thanks to @amalloy for suggesting this approach:

```
(define (repl exp1 exp2 exp3)
  (cond ; base case: list is empty
        ((null? exp3) exp3)
        ; base case: current element is the one we're looking for
        ((equal? exp1 exp3) exp2)
        ; recursive case: current element is a list
        ((pair? exp3) (cons (repl exp1 exp2 (first exp3)) 
                            (repl exp1 exp2 (rest exp3))))
        ; base case: current element is not the one we're looking for
        (else exp3)))
```

For example:

```
(repl '(f (g)) 'x '((a (b (c (d e (f (g))) h) i (j) (k (l (m)))))))
=> '((a (b (c (d e x) h) i (j) (k (l (m))))))
```

Comment: I suggest testing equality before testing for a pair. With your current solution, it's impossible to replace a list with another list.

Comment: @amalloy it's a bit trickier than that. I updated my answer, but can you think of a simpler way?

Comment: It's not actually trickier. I don't want to create an answer that's just "yours but simpler", so instead see https://pastebin.com/QbdaWSpm. You only need to care about listiness if you're not replacing, and only care about equality in the base case.

Comment: @amalloy omg, that's so simple! thanks for suggesting it, if you don't mind I'll add it to this answer, with due credit of course

Comment: FWIW I don't really agree that this is slower than your original version. `(equal? 'x '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))` short-circuits immediately when it discovers the two objects to compare have different types. So you only traverse over entire lists when it's actually necessary: when the item to replace is a list, which also has a prefix match with the item being considered.

Comment: @amalloy I did a quick benchmark replacing a symbol in a loop and in my laptop (admittedly, an old machine) the second version is about 40% slower than the first version. You're probably right in pointing that `equals?` is not to blame for the difference, though.

Comment: I suppose if we truly wanted to optimize, we'd write two different versions of the recursive part, with the cond clauses in different orders. Then before beginning the recursion, you check whether the item to be replaced is a list or not, and use the appropriate lambda for your recursion.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(define replace
  (lambda (x y l)
    (fold-right (lambda (e acc)
                  (if (pair? e)
                      (cons (replace x y e) acc)
                      (cons (if (eq? e x) y e) acc)))
                '()
                l)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't map be more relevant, since you're always consing the result in your fold?

Comment: @amalloy  yes, with `map` it works and the `cons`-es move implicitly inside map.  So, yes, correct.

Comment: Nice! it might be safer to use `equal?`. Also, as @amalloy pointed in my initial answer, this doesn't work for replacing lists

Comment: This general approach does work for replacing lists, just as well as yours does: you just have to (again) swap the order of equality testing and pair testing.

Answer (score 0):

This would be trivial in Common Lisp, which has a function [`subst`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm) that does exactly this kind of replacement.

```lisp
* (subst 'b 'a '((f a) (f (a))))
((F B) (F (B)))
* (subst 'x 'm '((a (b (c (d e (f (m))) h) i (j) (k (l (m)))) n) o (p)))
((A (B (C (D E (F (X))) H) I (J) (K (L (X)))) N) O (P))
* (subst 'x '(f (g)) '((a (b (c (d e (f (g))) h) i (j) (k (l (m)))))) :test #'equal)
((A (B (C (D E X) H) I (J) (K (L (M))))))
```

Unfortunately, the CL functions that work on trees/non-flat lists never made their way into the Scheme ecosystem. I wrote Racket implementations of many of them a while back; here's the one for `subst` for posterity's sake:

```lisp
(define (subst new old tree #:test [test eqv?] #:key [key identity])
  (cond
    ((test old (key tree)) new)
    ((pair? tree)
     (let ([new-car (subst new old (car tree) #:test test #:key key)]
           [new-cdr (subst new old (cdr tree) #:test test #:key key)])
       (if (and (eqv? (car tree) new-car)
                (eqv? (cdr tree) new-cdr))
           tree
           (cons new-car new-cdr))))
    (else tree)))
```

```lisp
> (subst 'b 'a '((f a) (f (a))))
'((f b) (f (b)))
> (subst 'x 'm '((a (b (c (d e (f (m))) h) i (j) (k (l (m)))) n) o (p)))
'((a (b (c (d e (f (x))) h) i (j) (k (l (x)))) n) o (p))
> (subst 'x '(f (g)) '((a (b (c (d e (f (g))) h) i (j) (k (l (m)))))) #:test equal?)
'((a (b (c (d e x) h) i (j) (k (l (m))))))
```

One thing to note about this implementation is that it reuses subtrees that aren't modified, potentially saving a lot of memory when used on big data structures with sparse replacements.